# Cannot change ng-class by function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I try to change a ng-class with an toggle-button. The class should be changed within a generated table, but It do not work. I´m not able to get access into the generated table.
Do you have a tip for me? Thank you so much for your help!

Here´s a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tjkagaj/3/)

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="markingDiagnosis(diagnosisModel)" ng-model="diagnosisModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">Diagnosis ICD</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="markingDrugs(drugsModel)" ng-model="drugsModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">Drugs</button>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="workspaceContainer" ng-repeat="sr in searchresults| filter:search.text" ng-show="currentWorkspace==sr">
        <table data-options="sr.tableOptions" bs-table-control></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Start Bootstrap-Table
// JavaScript source code
(function () {
    angular.module('bsTable', [])
        .directive('bsTableControl', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                options: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                $(element).bootstrapTable(scope.options);
                setInterval(function () {
                    $(element).bootstrapTable('resetView');
                }, 500);
            }
        };
    })
})();

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'bsTable']);
app.controller('QueryBuilderCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', '$compile',

function ($scope, $http, $compile) {
    var data = '{"group": {"operator": "AND","rules": []}}';

    function computed(group) {
        if (!group) return "";
        for (var str = "(",
        i = 0; i < group.rules.length; i++) {
            i > 0 && (str += " " + group.operator + " ");
            str += group.rules[i].group ? computed(group.rules[i].group) : group.rules[i].field + " " + group.rules[i].condition + " " + group.rules[i].data;
        }

        return str + ")";

    }

    //buttons
    $scope.diagnosisModel = 1;
    $scope.drugsModel = 1;
    $scope.markingDiagnosis = function (diagnosisModel) {
        if (diagnosisModel === 1) {
            $scope.markingDiagnosis = "red"
        } else {
            $scope.markingDiagnosis = "default"
        }
    };
    $scope.markingDrugs = function (drugsModel) {
        if (drugsModel === 1) {
            $scope.markingDrugs = "green"
        } else {
            $scope.markingDrugs = "default"
        }
    };




    //http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/getting-started.html
    $scope.searchresults = [];
    $scope.searchresults.push({
        name: 'Search Results'
    });
    //generate random rows
    $scope.searchresults.forEach(function (sr) {
        sr.rows = [];

        sr.rows[0] = {
            id: '0',
            name: 'Tom',
            age: '38',
            text: '<span ng-class="markingDiagnosis">Lorem ipsum dolor</span> sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <span ng-class="markingDrugs">Lorem ipsum dolor</span> invidunt ut labore et dolore'
        };
        sr.rows[1] = {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Peter',
            age: '40',
            text: '<span ng-class="markingDiagnosis">Lorem ipsum dolor</span> sit amet, consetetur sadipscing <span ng-class="markingDrugs">Lorem ipsum dolor</span> elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore'
        };


        sr.tableOptions = {
            data: sr.rows,
            rowStyle: function (row, index) {
                return {
                    classes: 'none'
                };
            },
            cache: false,
            height: 600,
            striped: true,
            pagination: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageList: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
            search: false,
            showColumns: true,
            showRefresh: false,
            minimumCountColumns: 2,
            clickToSelect: true,
            showToggle: true,
            maintainSelected: true,
            columns: [{
                field: 'state',
                checkbox: true
            }, {
                field: 'id',
                title: 'ID',
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'top',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'name',
                title: 'Name',
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'top',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'age',
                title: 'Age',
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'top',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'text',
                title: 'Text',
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'top',
                sortable: true
            }]
        };
    });


    $scope.changeCurrentWorkspace = function (sr) {
        $scope.currentWorkspace = sr;
    };

    //Select the workspace in document ready event
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $scope.changeCurrentWorkspace($scope.searchresults[0]);
        $scope.$apply();
    });

    // End Bootstrap-Table

}]);


// Test Highlight


app.filter('highlight', function ($sce) {
    return function (searchresults, phrase) {
        if (phrase) searchresults = searchresults.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
            '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

        return $sce.trustAsHtml(searchresults)
    }
})
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
.green {
    color: green;
}
.default {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer one problem in your code is the isolated scope and the other is the duplicated namings.

You could solve it like this:

1. pass your highlightling models into your directive e.g. `highlight.diagnosisModel`
2. re-compile your element after jQuery added everything. (It's important to remove the `bs-table-control` attribute before compiling to avoid an infinite loop.)

Please find the demo below or here at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/1tjkagaj/7/).

```js
// Start Bootstrap-Table
// JavaScript source code
(function () {
    angular.module('bsTable', [])
        .directive('bsTableControl', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                options: '=',
                highlight: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                console.log(scope.highlight);
                $(element).bootstrapTable(scope.options);
                $(element).bootstrapTable('resetView');
                element.removeAttr('bs-table-control');
                $compile($(element))(scope);
            }
        };
    })
})();

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'bsTable']);
app.controller('QueryBuilderCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', '$compile',

function ($scope, $http, $compile) {
    var data = '{"group": {"operator": "AND","rules": []}}';

    function computed(group) {
        if (!group) return "";
        for (var str = "(",
        i = 0; i < group.rules.length; i++) {
            i > 0 && (str += " " + group.operator + " ");
            str += group.rules[i].group ? computed(group.rules[i].group) : group.rules[i].field + " " + group.rules[i].condition + " " + group.rules[i].data;
        }

        return str + ")";

    }

    //buttons
    $scope.highlight = {
        diagnosisModel: 1,
        drugsModel: 1
    };

    $scope.markDiagnosis = function (diagnosisModel) {

        $scope.highlight.markingDiagnosis = diagnosisModel ? "red" : "default";
        console.log($scope.highlight.markingDiagnosis);
        /*if( diagnosisModel === 1 ){
        $scope.markingDiagnosis = "red"
    } else{
       $scope.markingDiagnosis = "default"
    }*/
    };
    $scope.markDrugs = function (drugsModel) {
        console.log(drugsModel);
        if (drugsModel === 1) {
            $scope.highlight.markingDrugs = "green"
        } else {
            $scope.highlight.markingDrugs = "default"
        }
    };




    //http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/getting-started.html
    $scope.searchresults = [];
    $scope.searchresults.push({
        name: 'Search Results'
    });
    //generate random rows
    $scope.searchresults.forEach(function (sr) {
        sr.rows = [];

        sr.rows[0] = {
            id: '0',
            name: 'Tom',
            age: '38',
            text: '<span ng-class="highlight.markingDiagnosis">Lorem ipsum dolor</span> sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <span ng-class="highlight.markingDrugs">Lorem ipsum dolor</span> invidunt ut labore et dolore'
        };
        sr.rows[1] = {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Peter',
            age: '40',
            text: '<span ng-class="highlight.markingDiagnosis">Lorem ipsum dolor</span> sit amet, consetetur sadipscing <span ng-class="highlight.markingDrugs">Lorem ipsum dolor</span> elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore'
        };


        sr.tableOptions = {
            data: sr.rows,
            rowStyle: function (row, index) {
                return {
                    classes: 'none'
                };
            },
            cache: false,
            height: 600,
            striped: true,
            pagination: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageList: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
            search: false,
            showColumns: true,
            showRefresh: false,
            minimumCountColumns: 2,
            clickToSelect: true,
            showToggle: true,
            maintainSelected: true,
            columns: [{
                field: 'state',
                checkbox: true
            }, {
                field: 'id',
                title: 'ID',
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'top',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'name',
                title: 'Name',
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'top',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'age',
                title: 'Age',
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'top',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                field: 'text',
                title: 'Text',
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'top',
                sortable: true
            }]
        };
    });


    $scope.changeCurrentWorkspace = function (sr) {
        $scope.currentWorkspace = sr;
    };

    //Select the workspace in document ready event
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $scope.changeCurrentWorkspace($scope.searchresults[0]);
        $scope.$apply();
    });

    // End Bootstrap-Table

}]);


// Test Highlight


app.filter('highlight', function ($sce) {
    return function (searchresults, phrase) {
        if (phrase) searchresults = searchresults.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
            '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

        return $sce.trustAsHtml(searchresults)
    }
})
```

```css
.red {
    color: red;
}
.green {
    color: green;
}
.default {
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/dist/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/extensions/filter/bootstrap-table-filter.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/dist/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-controller="QueryBuilderCtrl" ng-app="app">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="markDiagnosis(highlight.diagnosisModel)" ng-model="highlight.diagnosisModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">Diagnosis ICD</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="markDrugs(highlight.drugsModel)" ng-model="highlight.drugsModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">Drugs</button>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="workspaceContainer" ng-repeat="sr in searchresults| filter:search.text" ng-show="currentWorkspace==sr">
            <table data-options="sr.tableOptions" data-highlight="highlight" bs-table-control></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be very carefull, I could see that you use the same name for you function "markingDiagnosis" and your boolean "markingDiagnosis" you need to differentiate those (likewise for drugs).

Secondly, you should understand how the scope works in Angular. The directive that you are using to display your table and your controller do not share the same scope. Therefore you will have to share this value to the directive and watch for changes in your directive controller.

In my opinion I wouldn't rely on the module bsTable in which I cannot see any other opportunity than actually changing your entire row every time your watch for a change. A better way to do it would be to implement yourself the template in which you can toggle this class directly with the directive and therefore avoid using watch.